# thumbnail image that pop when selected (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, image, thumbnails

so Im wondering if it would be possible to,for example, I have a list of image,and when I select one from them,the image display bigger than the other to see it while the others and in thumbnail,and if I select another thumbnail the big image is replaced by the one I selected etc... but in javascript(and html)? And if so,whats the code structure to do that? **and without using stuff like jquery or similar javascript code generator;i want to do it manually by myself**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Lightbox jQuery plugin. It might be what you're looking for

http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9[1](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9)

Comment: thanks,however I modified my question; I forgot to say that I want to do it without external plugin or jquery;I want to do it manually by myself(code).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? (Or at least on the right track)

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeLp4/)**

HTML:

```
<a href="http://placehold.it/500">http://placehold.it/500</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/510">http://placehold.it/510</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/520">http://placehold.it/520</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/530">http://placehold.it/530</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/540">http://placehold.it/540</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/550">http://placehold.it/550</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/560">http://placehold.it/560</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/570">http://placehold.it/570</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/580">http://placehold.it/580</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/590">http://placehold.it/590</a>
<a href="http://placehold.it/600">http://placehold.it/600</a>

<div id="popup"><img src="" alt=""/></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
popup = document.getElementById("popup"),
img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    a[i].onclick = function(){
        popup.style.display="block";
        img.src = this.href;
        img.alt = this.innerHTML;
        return false;
    }
}
```